# How to check web browser URL | Python |

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

Is their any way to check particular URL in web browser

**I tried in this below format as well**

`print(webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new_tab('https://facebook.com`) and the output is `True` but also open the url.

**Code :**

```
import webbrowser

urls = ['facebook.com','https://instagram.com','http://twitter.com']
for i in urls:
    if webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new_tab(i) == False:
        webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new_tab('https://'+i)
    elif webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new_tab('https://'+i) == False:
        webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new_tab('http://'+i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the [validators](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)! package:

```
>>> import validators
>>> validators.url("http://google.com")
True
>>> validators.url("http://google")
ValidationFailure(func=url, args={'value': 'http://google', 'require_tld': True})
>>> if not validators.url("http://google"):
...     print "not valid"
... 
not valid
>>>
```